# Status 204 shows response.ok

Tags: javascript, http-status-codes, fetch-api

In my ASP.NET Core API backend, I send `Status 204` when there's no data but I noticed in the front end, my `fetch` call is still showing `response.ok`.

Two questions:

1. Is this normal behavior? I guess, it was a successful call so response could be OK, but it just threw me off.
2. What's the best way to check for `Status 204`?

My current code in my `React/Redux` app looks like this:

```
export const apiCall = () => {
   return (dispatch) => fetch("/api/get", fetchOptions)
      .then((response) => {
         if(response.ok) {
            // Do something
         } else {
            // Couldn't get data!
         }
      })
};
```

This is my standard code block in handling `fetch` calls. How should I modify it to handle `Status 204` scenarios?

Comment: 204 means *The server has successfully fulfilled the request and that there is no additional content to send in the response payload body.* - so, it is OK - if you want to signal an error, use an error response status!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to checking `Response.ok`, you can also check `Response.status`. Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/status):

> The status read-only property of the Response interface contains the status code of the response (e.g., 200 for a success).

`Response.ok` is only a check to see if the the `status` property is 200-299.

So, rather than just checking `ok`, you could do:

```
if (response.status === 200) {
  // Do something
} else if (response.status === 204) {
  // No data!
} else {
  // Other problem!
}
```

Comment: A bit verbose but I think this looks like a robust approach. Thank you!